# Google Play Product Id

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase

***[Edited as suggested by @Nick. Also made clearer the problem I am having. Also done a further edit to explain further.]***

In my app on the Google Play Dashboard I have created an in app purchase called test1. So what is the product id I put in the following?

```
String productString = "test1";
bp.purchase(this, /* "YOUR PRODUCT ID FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE" */ productString);
```

The `purchase` function is from [Android In-App Billing v3 Library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/README.md) as noted by @Nick .

The error I am getting when I just have `productString = "test1";` is it is saying:

```
Error
The item you requested is not available for purchase
```

When I do: **bp.purchase(this, "com.mywebsite.jon.myappname.test1");** to make it look as much as possible like the test purchase example

I get the error from Google Play:

```
Error
Error while retreiving information fro server. [DF-AA-20]
```

​
I am not sure if this is important:

1. I am at the very early stage of testing in Internal Testing (not
   Alpha or Beta testing).
2. My developer account and my purchaser accounts are different
3. I have the purchaser account email in my testers group

Comment: When asking a StackOverflow question, it is helpful to say what library you are using. In this case I had to Google search to find out you are using the anjlab library https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A product ID is described [in the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview). It is:

"Product ID - A unique, human readable ID for your product. Product IDs are also called SKUs in the Google Play Billing Library."

If you called your in app purchase "test1" then it is "test1".

-------- Edit

One problem (or good thing) with using 3rd party libraries (which is what the one is you link to is) rather than the Google Libraries is you don't get the official documentation. Google has produced [some ok documentation on testing in app billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing).

I'd go through all the steps on that page, and if it still doesn't work say the step where you failed. I suspect what is going wrong is you haven't yet published your app to the Play store. Before a real in-app product is purchased (as opposed to the test product names like 'android.test.purchased') The app must be published.

Don't worry if you don't want to publish your app to the world yet. You can use an [Internal Testing Track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213). An Internal test track publish won't be visible to anyone except the test accounts you add to it. And it won't affect your position in things like top charts for newly released apps. It is specifically there to test things like purchases or Google Play license verification.

Comment: But I thought it had a format with a load of `.` involved in it, ie like the test product `android.test.purchased`. From what you are saying Google Play will automatically know the purchase is coming from my specific program. Is that right?

Comment: I've extended my answer to give some more help.

Comment: Thanks for the extension. I had done that. So I have added more info in my OP to explain things further.

Comment: Hi @Nick. I found the specific problem I was suffering. Please include it in your answer. Thanks for your help, I will mark your solution as the answer. `I was going through the debugger. You cannot do that to test In App Purchases for non-test IAPs.`